# How to check if a website URL is running and active in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, http, web, url

I want to basically check if a website URL is legit and running, for example https://facebook.com should be accepted and http://lknavae.com should not be accepted. Only done in javascript!

How can I resolve this issue?

I used this solution that was given to a similar question however, this

```
function existsFile(url) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    try{
        http.send();
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
    return http.status!=404;

 }
```

However, for all most all websites it for `http.send()`it returns errors like [net::ERR_FAILED 301](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g5P1.png)

And for fake domains like http://lknavae.com it `http.send()` returns this instead of 404 [net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2kpF.png)

Comment: There is nothing you can do about cors error except send a request on a server, not in a browser

Comment: I think you have 2 options, either try to fetch a "static asset URL" or implement your approach on the server (because you can't do this on the client side due to CORS)

Answer (score -2):

can you try something like that?

```
function existsFile(url) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('GET', url);
    try{
        http.send();
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }

    http.onload = () => {
    console.log('DONE: ', http.status);
    };
 }
```

for better reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status

In your're code example you just returned a boolean instead of the status code. The "!=" operator will just check if its true or false and return it.

You also tried to run you're code sync with the third parameter in `"http.open"` but there's no need for that. You can let it run async and just wait with `"http.onload"` till it completed loading (check the reference).

Due to the fact that it is ajax you should handle all you need to do with the result inside the request like the `console.log('DONE: ', http.status)`.

EDIT: You need to handle probably CORS (Cross-Origin) before. Because you're browser will otherwise deny it and you're code fails.
But you can try the code on you're local Network.

Comment: Hi, could you please clearify what I could explain better in this answer so it doesn't needs to be downvoted?

Comment: You should explain how to handle the CORS problem.